# Snowflake fix for primary key that has become negative due to int32 overflow?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am accessing some data via the Snowflake marketplace:

Annoyingly, one of the tables has a clear "overflow" in thir primary key.

The `rowId` column increments almost sequentially until 2,101,261,865 then the next number is -2,147,483,617 and it starts incrementing from there.

I'm trying to clean this by making all of these numbers positive integers. I am currently doing:

```
SELECT 
   rowId + IFF(rowId < 0, POWER(2,31), 0) AS rowId, 
   ... 
FROM bigTable
```

But is there a better way?

Comment: Negative row identifiers may be unusual, but why do you need to remap it? As long as the column contains a unique value, it serves as a row identifier regardless of the sign of the value.

Comment: It makes the logic for "recentdata" as of a given period much simpler. This way I can use the `rowId` column in incremental runs for DBT

Comment: I try to avoid business logic around primary keys, but if you don't have a timestamp available to distinguish recent data, that may be your next best option.

Comment: The data vendor often backdates data (ie. they insert data today with a timestamp of 2019-10-09); so the PK check is my best bet to detect new data

Comment: Perhaps two parts to your DBT runs: one part to accommodate the pattern of positive PK values, one part to accommodate negative PK values (if the pattern is identifiable as positive keys always increment and negative keys always increment).

Comment: Much easier to create a view over the raw table with the PK fixed

Answer (score 0):

This was my answer in the end:

```
-- rawTableName.sql

WITH rawTableName AS (
    SELECT * FROM {{ source('SOURCE', 'rawTableName') }}
)

SELECT 
    rowId + IFF(rowId < 0, 4294967296, 0) AS "rowId ",
    { OTHER COLUMNS }
FROM rawTableName
```